# Execute code when Access database is closed using form close

Tags: ms-access, vba

My AutoExec macro executes code that opens a hidden form

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmAppClose", , , , , acHidden
```

Now I want to catch when that form is closed to execute some cleanup code. All the documentation (and yes, posts here) show using a Sub like this

```
Private Sub Form_Close()
    'do your stuff here '
End Sub
```

However, I cannot get this to work. The Form_Close() is never entered. Any suggestions? I do realize this question has been asked a few times here but there is something rudimentary I must be missing.

Comment: Did you set OnClose event on the hidden form?

Comment: How do you set that event? Maybe this is what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

It is not always the better event as the form doesn't exist anymore.

Often it is better to run such stuff before closing the form, at the unload event:

```
Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
    'do your stuff here 
End Sub
```

Comment: Then something else is going on. If the property sheet shows _[Event Procedure]_ for these events they will be called.